# Object possibly NULL in angular

Tags: angular

The error shows that the object possibly NULL in angular but it shows in html file. how to handle it.

```
<div class="error-text" *ngIf="entity_id.invalid && (entity_id.dirty || entity_id.touched)">
                                    <div *ngIf="entity_id.errors.required">
                                        {{clientLbl}} required.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1zkl.png)

Comment: you can use ? operator

Answer (score 0):

Sometime optional properties have this issue, it is becuase you have defined optional in type. easy fix is using [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
<div class="error-text" *ngIf="entity_id.invalid && (entity_id.dirty || entity_id.touched)">
                                    <div *ngIf="entity_id?.errors?.required">
                                        {{clientLbl}} required.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: it still shows same error